# Why doesn't R allow $ operator on atomic vectors?

Tags: r

The following will throw the error "Error in v$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" (at least in R version 2.14.1):

```
v <- c(a='a',b='b')
v$a
```

Apparently, R previously allowed this, which makes me curious as to why.

EDIT: As pointed out below, `v$a` would have returned NULL in the earlier versions. Changed "fairly recently" to "previously", since I based this on old Internet forums and have been corrected below.

Comment: The LINK provided by Tyler shows that your version of "fairly recently" is arguably rather distorted and it even suggests that it might never have been a productive strategy, because it would have returned `NULL` when you appear to think it should have returned "a".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the reason is that the use of `v$a` vs. `v[['a']]` is considered less safe.

EDIT:  Check out this [LINK](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e3/help/07/12/5772.html) for more details.

Comment: @Matt Safe from evil bots bent on world domination

Comment: Safe from things like this: R> l <- list(aa=2,bb=3) --
R> l$a
[1] 2 --
R> l[["a"]]
NULL --

Comment: As the link I gave and Hansi pointed out it has to do with R's lazy evaluation

Comment: @TylerRinker, that answers my question the best so far. Perhaps you would like to promote this (not the evil bots comment, but the one with the link) to an answer?

Comment: Well, Hansi's example uses partial matching and that is clearly documented in the manpage. That kind of saftey isn't usually a concern in R, is it?: 
> F <- TRUE \n
> if (F) "true" else "false" \n
[1] "true" \n
... just found out that you're not even allowed to define your own method for `$` with signature (x = "numeric"). Wow.

Comment: Link does not work

Answer (score 6):

Third paragraph of the Details section of `?"$"`:

> ‘$’ is only valid for recursive objects, and is only discussed in the
>   section below on recursive objects.  Its use on non-recursive objects
>   was deprecated in R 2.5.0 and removed in R
>   2.7.0.

R-2.7.0 was released in April, 2008.  Four years is far from "recent", but maybe you have been a few versions behind for awhile?

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it was deprecated for non-recursive objects? It is fairly recent in terms of languages ... kind of :-). I've actually only been using R for about a year, so this change was before my time.

Comment: @Jonathan: see the link/discussion in the comments of [Tyler Rinker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9824326/271616).