# Error in panel$intname : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I am working on the r panel package. Now if I have a function that uses a radiogroup button, and if i attempt to run the function from inside the rpanel menu, I get this error:

```
Error in panel$intname : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

However if I run the function per sé i.e. not from inside the rpanel menu, but by calling it independently, the above error doesn't appear. Here is a simple example. Try in 2 ways (1) run the whole code and click on Addition and then click Add in the menu (2) run the add function alone and call with add(). The former results in the above error and the latter doesn't.  Also, i saw that this error comes only when i have a rp.radiogroup in my panel.

I saw the post in [Why doesn't R allow $ operator on atomic vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824268/why-doesnt-r-allow-operator-on-atomic-vectors) but how do i solve my issue? My sample Code is below:

```
install.packages(c("rpanel","tkrplot"))
my.menu <- function(panel) {

library(rpanel,tkrplot)

if (panel$menu=="Add"){
add()
  }
else 
panel
}


main.panel <- rp.control(title = "Main Menu",size=c(200,150))
rp.menu(panel = main.panel, var = menu,
    labels = list(list("Addition", "Add")),action = my.menu)


#  function to do adddition

add <- function(){

my.draw <- function(panel) {
 if(panel$vals=="numbers"){
  val<-as.numeric(panel$nmbr1)+as.numeric(panel$nmbr2)
 }
else if(panel$vals=="strings"){
  val <- paste(as.character(panel$nmbr1), "and" ,as.character(panel$nmbr2))
}
plot(1:10, 1:10, type="n", xlab="", ylab="",
axes=FALSE, frame = TRUE)
text(5, 5, paste("Result: ", val),cex=1.4)
panel
}



my.redraw <- function(panel) {
rp.tkrreplot(panel, my.tkrplot)
 panel
}

my.panel <- rp.control(title = "Addition")
rp.textentry(panel = my.panel, var = nmbr1,
 labels = "First:     ", action = my.redraw, initval="100")
rp.textentry(panel = my.panel, var = nmbr2,
           labels = "Second:", action = my.redraw, initval="200")
rp.radiogroup(panel = my.panel, var = vals,
            values = c("numbers", "strings"),
            action = my.redraw, title = "Type")
rp.tkrplot(panel = my.panel, name = my.tkrplot, plotfun = my.draw)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply escape using $: Change

> panel$vals

to:

> panel["vals"]

Comment: Ali, i am not using panel$intname anywhere. i am calling the variable "vals" as panel$vals.

Comment: I acted as your question topic. The answer is now refined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali. i changed panel$vals to panel["vals"] as per your suggestion. But no luck. Getting the same error msg when i try to run the func. add from the panel GUI but not when the function add() is run from command line.

Comment: Now that you don't have the $ operator, how such an error can occur? Are you sure this error belongs to this special part of your code?

Comment: Ali, i really dont know what is causing the error. Like i said, the function returns no error if i just call it as add(), only when i call it from the gui menu i.e. click Addition > click Add, i get the error.