# not able to read the columns in summary function

Tags: r

```
dput(x)
structure(c("2005-01-01:  1  ", "2005-01-02:  1  ", "2005-01-03:  1  ", 
"2005-01-04:  1  ", "2005-01-05:  1  ", "2005-01-06:  1  ", "(Other)   :724  ", 
"Min.   :  1.700  ", "1st Qu.:  3.062  ", "Median :  4.345  ", 
"Mean   :  6.267  ", "3rd Qu.:  7.435  ", "Max.   : 22.100  ", 
"NA's   :666.000  ", "Min.   :  0.2490  ", "1st Qu.:  0.6182  ", 
"Median :  1.0500  ", "Mean   :  2.2679  ", "3rd Qu.:  2.7825  ", 
"Max.   : 10.8000  ", "NA's   :666.0000  ", "Min.   :101  ", 
"1st Qu.:101  ", "Median :101  ", "Mean   :101  ", "3rd Qu.:101  ", 
"Max.   :101  ", NA), .Dim = c(7L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""), c("Dat", "Var1", "Var2", "Name")), class = "table")
```

I am trying to look do this:

```
x$Var1
```

and getting this error:

```
Error in x$Var1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

any idea, what I am doing is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't R allow $ operator on atomic vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824268/why-doesnt-r-allow-operator-on-atomic-vectors)

Comment: But it's not an atomic vector.  It seems to be an object of class `table`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, thank you. but it is still not working for me. I did x<-data.frame(x), no luck either.

Comment: Please be aware that what you're trying to do is sort of an abuse of the output of `summary`. Don't confuse presentation with content. Just because R displays something in the console in a nice, pretty tabular format doesn't mean that it's essentially a data frame and can be treated as such. It's just as easy to calculate all these quantities yourself and return them in a data frame that's more amenable to subsetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
> x[,'Var1']

"Min.   :  1.700  " "1st Qu.:  3.062  " "Median :  4.345  " "Mean   :  6.267  " "3rd Qu.:  7.435  " 

"Max.   : 22.100  " "NA's   :666.000  "
```

A simple example:

```
y <- rep(letters[1:3], each=10)
table(y)
## y
##  a  b  c 
## 10 10 10 

table(y)$a
## Error in table(y)$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: I don't think the error message is misleading at all. If one does not understand that matrices are really folded atomic vectors, then one is ill-equipped to use R effectively. one ends up doign really damaging operations like `as.data.frame(cbind(object))` and wondering why all the attributes are gone.

Answer (score 3):

I am reading between the lines a little here, but to get the sort of data you want for each variable, you may be better off doing something like:

```
# create some test data
> test <- data.frame(Dat=1:10,Var1=1:10)
> result <- lapply(test,summary)
> result
$Dat
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00 

$Var1
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
> result$Var1
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00
```

Comment: And the result is actually a vector of numeric, rather than oddly-formed character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew is giving you misleading advice rather than R being the entity which is misleading you. The error messages are accurate and if you pay attention to then you can learn valuable lessons. R tables are really matrices. They return TRUE from is.matrix and all the usual access methods work. The `$` operator is for lists (of which 'dataframe' is a subclass ... but 'matrix' is not.) Notice that he offered you an access method that used the fact that matrices respond to access by named dimensional indices.