# Error in NJ$Population : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

Im working on heatmaps for New Jersey population, the dataset is called "NJ" and it has a column called "Population". I want to define the color buckets for the range of population. However, when I use the code given below, it always gives me an error of :
Error in NJ$Population : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
 NJpalette<-brewer.pal(7,"Blues")
 NJ$colorBuckets<-as.numeric(cut(NJ$Population,c(0,150000,30000,450000,600000,750000,900000,1000000)))
```

I dont unerstand why it happens, I read that instead of using $ I could call population using

```
NJ[Population]
```

However, even that doesnt help. Can someone please suggest how to go forward

Comment: `NJ<-brewer.pal(7,"Blues")#
Error: could not find function "brewer.pal"`  Please do update with the package that has the relevant function.

Comment: I assume it is from `RColorBrewer`.  Check the `str(NJ)`.  It is a character vector.   `str(NJ)#
 chr [1:7] "#EFF3FF" "#C6DBEF" "#9ECAE1" "#6BAED6" "#4292C6" ...`  No idea how you got `NJ$Population` that doesn't exist in `NJ` or at least not shown in your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't R allow $ operator on atomic vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824268/why-doesnt-r-allow-operator-on-atomic-vectors)

Comment: @akrun i have update my question, NJ is the df and Population is a column in it

Comment: @Swarnalakshmi  If that is the case, please do show the code in the post to make it reproducible.  The thing that changed is `NJ` became `NJpalette`.  The reason we ask for providing reproducible code is to solve your problem more quickly rather than guessing what might be the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @akrun thanks akrun, I resolved it. Careless mistake! Thanks for correcting :)